# How to program in Selenium for webpages with flash content?

Tags: selenium

I want to test a application that is hosted on skytap inside a windows OS.I am not able to detect any of the objects using selenium..

But I presume with Flash I would be able to detect objects and automate it..Can someone tell me how to do coding for automating flash objects like those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use selenium to interact with flash 10.0 or higher for security reasons. Adobe removed the ability to interact with flash objects programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Selenium to interact with Flash but you SURE CAN use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to interact with it.

Now, while you would use Sikuli for something like a Crystal Report or Flash, or something outside of the browsers border, you might rather use Webdrivers "Action" class to do manual mouse clicks on dynamic Javascript items within your browsers page border.

So, there are 3 paradigms:

```
   1.  Normal "findby" webdriver actions
   2.  Physical mouse clicks without the browser window with Action class
   3.  Physical clicks of non-web items using Sikuli by matching a screenshot image.
```